# How to replace a occurance of a string with another string and count the number of changes made?

Tags: java, string, replace

I've been stuck on this for days and I don't know how to replace "is" with "was" and count the changes made. My code is down below.

public class BasicString {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;
    int count = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter text");
        s = scan.nextLine();
        String t = new String("is");
        String j = new String("was");
        if (s.equals("The end")) {
            break;
        }
        // IndexOf method used with variable count to see if "Is" is inserted 
        if (s.indexOf(t) != -1) {
            String r = t.replace("is", "was");

            count++;
            System.out.println(count + r);

        }

    }
```

The assignment is this - 
Using the string methods that we have learned so far, write a program that will allow the user to type in line of text until the user types in the phrase "The end" on a line by itself. The program will replace every occurrence of "is" with the string "was" and count the number of changes made. Strings have two basic methods that you will need for this assignment:

Comment: If you're only interested in the number of `String`s replaced, then why do you need to bother actually replacing them? You can just count how many needles there are in your haystack.

Comment: How do I get it to replace "is" with "was" every-time a text is inputed. Im confused on that part, my professor gave me the example methods down below.                     s.concat(t) - which returns a string consisting of the strings s and t concatenated (or joined) together.
s.substring(i, j) - which returns a substring of s beginning at character i and ending at character j-1.
s.substring(i) - which returns a substring of s beginning at character i and ending at the end of s.